# Powershell archive script

Tags: powershell

I've just started working with PowerShell and with a bit of help from a book and a lot of Google searching I've come up with this script.  The problem I'm having is that it isn't keep the folder structure.  It is checking one network location for files that are over 5 days old.  If it is older than 5 days, it moves it to a different network location.  At the second location it checks for files over 30 days old and deletes those files.

```
$movepath = "C:\test"
$archpath = "C:\test2"
$deletepath = "C:\files"
$movedays = "5"
$deletedays = "30"
$datetime = get-date
$deletelog = "c:\logs\deletelog.txt"
$movelog = "c:\logs\movelog.txt"
$errorlog = "c:\logs\errorlog.txt"

write-progress -activity "Archiving Data" -status "Progress:"

Get-Childitem -Path $movepath -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$movedays)} |
 ForEach {
$filename = $_.fullname
try
{
Move-Item $_.FullName -destination $archpath -force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
"Moved $filename to $archpath at $datetime successfully" | add-content $movelog
}
catch
{
"Error moving $filename: $_ " | add-content $errorlog
}
}
Get-Childitem -Path $deletepath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$deletedays)} |
ForEach {
$filename = $_.fullname
try
{
Remove-Item $_.FullName -force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
"Removed $filename at $datetime successfully" | add-content $deletelog
}
catch
{
 "Error moving $filename: $_ " | add-content $errorlog
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in logic to maintain the folder structure.

```
$FileName = $_.FullName.Replace($MovePath, $ArchPath);
```